# Apache Pig - How to maintain a distributed look-up table for my python UDF to access?

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

In my Pig script, there is one intermediate step where i wanted to map the resulting server hostnames to application names. I have a text file (~10k records) created from database with this mapping. But i am unsure how to distribute this text file into pig and access them at runtime. Please help..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for using Pig's [fragment-replicate join](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/perf.html#replicated-joins) algorithm. You can just load your lookup table as a Pig relation and join it against your actual data.

```
A = LOAD 'data1' USING ... AS ...;
B = LOAD 'lookuptable' USING ... AS ...;
C = JOIN A BY join_key, B BY join_key USING 'replicated';
```

Note that the table you want loaded into memory should be on the right side of the join as I've shown above.